# php mysql today's sum and monthly sum

Tags: php, mysql, date, sum

I am trying to calculate the total of today's sales but this doesn't work.
It works, if I remove the date part...

```php
# This works and will gives out the total:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(grand_total) AS value_sum FROM order");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['value_sum'];

# This doesn't work:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(grand_total) AS value_sum FROM new_order WHERE date = CURDATE()");
$query = mysql_query($result) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Also, how can I get the monthly total of this column after this?

Comment: I'm surprised the first one works. Reversed words usually need to be back-ticked. For example in your statement I'd expect order and date to need to be `\`order\`` and  `\`date\``. If you execute the query's direct on the DB what error do you get?

Comment: The first one works without any error message, the second code doesn't return anything and even the 500 error...

Comment: Do you have mysql error? Do this: `mysql_query("...") or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());`. What type of fileld is `date`? If not `DATE` what values are in this field?

Comment: @Glavić, the date is date with this format 0000:00:00 00:00:00

Comment: I did this and it only says "error:"        $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(grand_total) AS value_sum FROM order WHERE date = CURDATE()");
$query = mysql_query($result) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['value_sum'];

Comment: Wrong! Try this `$sql = "SELECT SUM(grand_total) AS value_sum FROM new_order WHERE date = CURDATE()";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());`

Comment: It comes back blank! no error and no result! But there are values in the database...

Comment: is it possible that the date is different on the server?

Comment: Just select current date from db and see if it is ok... `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT CURDATE()")); var_dump($row);`

Comment: yep, lolll, the server was one day behind!

Comment: @Glavić, your code works now! thank you!!!

Comment: do you know how can I get the monthly total?

Comment: `... WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `date` field is `DATETIME` type, then try this sql statement:

```sql
SELECT SUM(`grand_total`) AS value_sum 
FROM `order`
WHERE DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: I did that and i get this:  Error: Query was empty

Comment: How can query be empty? Did you try it this way: `$sql = "SQL IN THE ANSWER"; $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());` ?